# Azure Function ARM template deletes the existing application settings those are not part of the template file

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-functions-runtime

I have created function app with default application settings using ARM template. Unfortunately, when the ARM template deployed it deleted any application settings that were not defined in the ARM template.

This is ARM template using for function app:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('fnapp', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the function app that you wish to create."
      }
    },
    "newOrExisting": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "new",
        "existing"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Choose the app service plan based on these values"
      }
    },
    "existingHostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the existing hosting plan"
      }
    },
    "existingResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the existing resource group"
      }
    },
    "newHostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the new hosting plan"
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "D1",
        "F1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P1V2",
        "P2V2",
        "P3V2",
        "I1",
        "I2",
        "I3",
        "Y1"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "S1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The pricing tier for the hosting plan."
      }
    },
    "workerSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "0",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The instance size of the hosting plan (small, medium, or large)."
      }
    },
    "applicationInsightsName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Application Insights Name."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Storage Account."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "runtime": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "dotnet",
      "allowedValues": [
        "node",
        "dotnet",
        "java"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The language worker runtime to load in the function app."
      }
    },
    "identityType": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Identity type"
      }
    },
    "functionRuntimeVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "~3",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The runtime version for the function app"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "serverFarmId": "[ if(equals(parameters('newOrExisting'),'new'),resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',parameters('newHostingPlanName')), concat(subscription().id,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('existingResourceGroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/',parameters('existingHostingPlanName')))]",
    "functionWorkerRuntime": "[parameters('runtime')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('newOrExisting'),'new')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('newHostingPlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "Name": "[parameters('sku')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('newHostingPlanName')]",
        "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName'))]"
      ],
      "identity": {
        "type": "[parameters('identityType')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[variables('serverFarmId')]",
        "httpsOnly": true,
        "siteConfig": {
          "alwaysOn": true,
          "ftpsState": "FtpsOnly",
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
                        {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "[parameters('functionRuntimeVersion')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "~10"
            },
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName')), '2020-02-02-preview').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "[variables('functionWorkerRuntime')]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('applicationInsightsName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('applicationInsightsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ApplicationId": "[parameters('applicationInsightsName')]",
        "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

I have referred [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11718) git hub issue but still it is open.

So, can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide your template?

Comment: @JoyWang, Please look at my updated question. I have added arm template for the function app

Comment: Any other concerns about this issue?

Comment: Currently, I have added default settings in `Microsoft.Web/sites/config`. Once I have provisioned the arm template then the function app will create with default settings under `Configuration' section. After that I am trying to deploy the .zip package then the few application settings were added automatically in the function app. But whenever redeploy with new changes of function app arm-template then I lost application settings those are created through .zip package or manually created from portal.

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to include all the appsettings in the template in every deployment if you want to add new appsettings.

Comment: Yes i.e., right, but in case of prod function deployment, If I have add all those prod settings in arm template is not the secure right

Comment: Yes, but looks there is no direct way to solve the issue currently, you could try the workaround with [list()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11718#issuecomment-732348273) and [union()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11718#issuecomment-715404941), get the old appsettings and combine them with the new settings(not test, not sure if it will work).

Answer (score 5):

This is a normal phenomenon, when you deploy the template, there are two modes, `Complete` and `Incremental`, but even if with `Incremental` mode, the `appsettings` which is a child resource of `Microsoft.Web/sites/config` will be overwritten if you provide new values(web app and function app are the same).

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#incremental-mode

[image]

So in your case, if you want to keep the default settings, you also need to add them to your temaplate.

Comment: Adding app settings to the template doesn't create default settings--it overwrites them every time in our experience.